# Pycharm : Return type of a function in the auto-completion window?

Tags: python, ide, pycharm

I'd like to know if it's possible to force PyCharm considering types in a static way (like Java IDEs for instance).

Right now I've found some tools that help to check types on runtime, like Pyre but that's not what I'm looking for.

Is there a way to have str instead of the A object type ?
Please have a look at this explicit use case : https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcNGn.jpg

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This `A` means `foo` completions suggestion comes from `A` class not `foo` returns `A`.

Comment: Exactly, and I'd like to replace that like on Eclipse with Java, where returning type is displayed for example.
Thanks for your reply by the way.

Comment: Uh, I see. Unfortunately, there's no such possibility yet, but feel free to submit a feature request in [PyCharm's bug tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY).

Comment: Yeah why not. How about developing my own plug-in, does that sound realistic to you ? The algo is about evaluating types hints and/or comments by using pycharm's code introspection hooks. 
I doubt you guys from Jetbrains are going to dev the feature only for my isolated use case, which must not be common.

Thank you Pavel.

Comment: Our completion items can not be customized by plugins (see [sources](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/python/src/com/jetbrains/python/psi/resolve/CompletionVariantsProcessor.java#L64)), but you could implement your own [completion contributor](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/master/python/src/com/jetbrains/python/codeInsight/completion) and increase priority for its items (see [example](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/python/src/com/jetbrains/python/codeInsight/completion/PythonCompletionWeigher.java)).

Comment: @user2235698 does this problem has any solutions yet? it does seem to me weird that class name is used in suggestions box but the return type